# Finding text to compare true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, compare

I'm trying to build out a json object in javascript/jquery that compares . Here's what I have

html:

```
<div class="field">
    <div>size</div>
    <div>large</div>
    <div>medium</div>
    <div>number</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
selectedObj = {
  'fieldSize':false,
  'sizeXSmall':false,
  'sizeSmall':false,
  'sizeMedium':false,
  'sizeLarge':false,
  'sizeXLarge':false,
  'fieldName':false,
  'fieldNum':false
};

if(jQuery('.field div:contains("size")')){selectedObj['fieldSize'] = true}
if(jQuery('.field div:contains("xs")')){selectedObj['sizeXSmall'] = true}
if(jQuery('.field div:contains("small")')){selectedObj['sizeSmall'] = true}
if(jQuery('.field div:contains("medium")')){selectedObj['sizeMedium'] = true}
if(jQuery('.field div:contains("large")')){selectedObj['sizeLarge'] = true}
if(jQuery('.field div:contains("xl")')){selectedObj['sizeXLarge'] = true}
if(jQuery('.field div:contains("name")')){selectedObj['fieldName'] = true}
if(jQuery('.field div:contains("number")')){selectedObj['fieldNum'] = true}
```

So ideally I would end up with an object that looks like this:

```
selectedObj = {
  'fieldSize':true,
  'sizeXSmall':false,
  'sizeSmall':false,
  'sizeMedium':true,
  'sizeLarge':true,
  'sizeXLarge':false,
  'fieldName':false,
  'fieldNum':true
};
```

I instead end up with an object where everything is true. Here is an example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/vz600nd7/
```

Also, when I console log it before an after it looks like this:

[image: preview mismatch]

It looks like the 'preview' is giving the right info but the actual view is not.

Comment: `jQuery('.field div:contains("size")')` returns an jQuery object which is always true so `jQuery('.field div:contains("size")').length`

Comment: Don't trust `console.log` when logging objects. It tends to provide a live view of the object, so even if properties are updated *after* your `console.log` runs, the console still shows the updated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, `jQuery(selector)` will return a jQuery object which will always be a truthy value. So your if condition will get executed every time.

I will try something like

```js
var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).appendTo($log)
  }
})();

var map = {
  'fieldSize': 'size',
  'sizeXSmall': 'xs',
  'sizeSmall': 'small',
  'sizeMedium': 'medium',
  'sizeLarge': 'large',
  'sizeXLarge': 'xl',
  'fieldName': 'name',
  'fieldNum': 'number'
};
selectedObj = {
  'fieldSize': false,
  'sizeXSmall': false,
  'sizeSmall': false,
  'sizeMedium': false,
  'sizeLarge': false,
  'sizeXLarge': false,
  'fieldName': false,
  'fieldNum': false
};

var $els = jQuery('.field div');
$.each(map, function(key, value) {
  selectedObj[key] = $els.is(':contains("' + value + '")')
});
log('After: ' + JSON.stringify(selectedObj))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <div>size</div>
  <div>large</div>
  <div>medium</div>
  <div>number</div>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to detect, if object exists, use:

```
if($('.field div:contains("size")')[0]) selectedObj['fieldSize'] = true;
...
```